# Значение слова "продучка"

Tags: значение-слов

В сказке 'Иван Царевич и Змей' Ивану помогает сучка-продучка. Сучка, понятно, собака. А что значит 'продучка'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никаких сведений кроме самой сказки найти не удалось, поэтому простор для фантазии полный.
Путём нехитрых размышлений у меня родились следующие предположения:

1. Продучка, по аналогии с Ревунком и Сосунком, также фигурирующими в сказке - это существительное образованное от глагола.
2. Глаголы могли стать продучкой, если начальная форма у них "продуть", продучить" или "продучать". Соответственно сучка у нас может быть "продутой", "продученной" или "продучатой".
3. ПродУтой сучка может быть, например, если голос свой посадила (продула), или её проиграли (продули) кому-либо. Вторая версия ни на чём не основана, а первая имеет аналогию в виде необходимого спутника, кобелька-ревунка. Ещё продувным человеком по [Далю](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/338914) называют хитрого плута и обманщика, что в какой-то мере можно отнести и к героине сказки, правда тогда она должна была быть "продувка", но для точности рифмы могли и подкорректировать звучание.
4. Что такое "продучить" совсем непонятно, а "продучать" - может действительно, вариант продуктивная.

Ещё факт, выясненный во время поиска: [Дучками](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/232882) в западных губерниях называли лунки, ямки, но как это связать с собакой через приставку про- - непонятно.

Comment: ЗдОрово! Особенно про плута и обманщика, собака-то по сказке очень хитрая, чему и учит Ивана-царевича!  

У @grumant выше тоже "продувная бестия",  значение фразеологизма - плут, хитрец, пройдоха.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что имеется в виду самка-производительница, самка-мать. (Продуктирует-производит. Хотя насчет продуч- /продукт- большие сомнения: сказка, наверно, более древняя. ).

Сучка-продучка помогает советами Ивану-царевичу, а в финале спасает его от смерти, зализывая рану (фактически оживляет его).

Кроме сучки-продучки, в сказке фигурируют еще кобель-ревун и кобель-лизун. Последний, видимо, щенок:)

Comment: Как только не набирала в поисковике - ничего не находится, кроме
самой сказки.

Comment: Собачка была продувной бестией)